# Alternating direction implicit method for finite difference solver of pde in Python

Tags: python, differential-equations, pde

I am working on implementing the [Alternating direction implicit method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_direction_implicit_method) to solve [FitzHugh–Nagumo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FitzHugh%E2%80%93Nagumo_model) reaction diffusion model. I have found a Python implementation example for it in a [blog](http://georg.io/2013/12/Alternating_Direction_Implicit_Method/), but I think there is an error in the method - in the stencil presented here:
[image]
Shouldn't it be half time step size multiplying the reaction term ***f*** ?

Comment: You'll maybe get more answers on http://math.stackexchange.com/, this is more of a math problem.

Comment: Or at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com, where there are experts for large scale scientific computing. -- It is also the factors 2 in the denominators `D/(2*dp^2)` that seem dubious, the linked wikipedia page seems to confirm this. -- And why is there a `dt` at all, the other terms are all full difference quotients, no infinitesimal factors unbound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the difference quotients by the differential quotients, one gets

```
U_t = D/2 * U_xx + D/2 * U_yy + Δt*f
```

in both instances, which is not the equation

```
U_t = D * (U_xx + U_yy) + f
```

that was the originally posed task.

So the coefficients should be `1/(Δt/2)` as it was at `U_t`, `D/(Δp^2)` at `U_pp`, `p=x,y` and `1` for `f`.

It seems the formula is a mix-up of the one with difference quotients and the next stage where it gets multiplied by `Δt/2`.

And in that next formula one does not need new constants as indeed `α_p=σ_p`, `p=x,y` and then you are right that the factor of `f` should be `Δt/2`.